# calculate student total marks and insert that total in another table with the id of that student together

Tags: php, mysql

I'm developing a simple student information system, for now i have 300 students and six subjects, so when i want to add marks obtained by each student i use html form and php script to add those marks, for each student i add marks for six subjects that is one subject at a time, so i'm asking if there is the way where by php can allow me retrieve one student and add all the marks for the six subjects at once and then take another and so on. Also i want to calculate total marks for each student and store those total in another table with respective student id so that i can know who is the first student and who is the last by using that total marks of each student.

here is the way i'm doing right now

```
<?php error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>
<html>
<body>
<div>
<div>
<form action="connmarks.php" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr><td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td><p>Adding Student Results</p></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="9%">Student Code<?php echo $mstudentcode;?></td>
    <td width="17%"><input name="student_code" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo $studentcode;?>" /></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="10%">Subject Code<?php echo $msubjectcode;?></td>
    <td width="18%"><input name="subject_code" type="text" size="30"  value="<?php echo $subject_code;?>"/></td></tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="12%">Marks<?php echo $mmark;?></td>
    <td width="34%"><input name="mark" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo $mark;?>"/></td>

    </tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;
      </td>
    </tr>
     <tr><td colspan="4">&nbsp;</td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="6">&nbsp;</td></tr>
     <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td><td colspan="6"><input type="submit" name="save" value="Add Marks" /></td>
     </tr>
     <tr><td colspan="6"><?php echo $sms1.$sms.$sms2;?></td></tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">Copyright <?php echo date("Y", time()); ?></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


<?php error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE); ?>
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['save']))
{
//  validating student code
    if(empty($_POST['student_code']))
    {
        $mstudentcode='<font color="red"><b>**</b></font>';
    }
    else
    {
        $student_code=$_POST['student_code'];
    }
//  validation for kiswahili subject
    if(empty($_POST['subject_code']))
    {
        $msubjectcode='<font color="red"><b>**</b></font>';
    }
    else
    {
        $subject_code=$_POST['subject_code'];
    }
// validating english subject
    if(empty($_POST['mark']))
    {
        $mmark='<font color="red"><b>**</b></font>';
    }
    else
    {
        $mark=$_POST['mark'];
    }
// checking if there is any error message, if no error proceed, if there is error, display the error
//  Then exit the script and redirect at the same page
    if($mstudentcode||$msubjectcode||$mmark||$sms)
    {
        $sms1='<font color="red"><b>Error found,please check **</b></font><br/>';
        include 'addmarks.php';
        exit;
    }
// if there is no error include connection file
    if($student_code&&$subject_code&&$mark)
    {
//      include 'mysqli_connect.php';
      require_once ('../../mysqli_connect.php');
        $addmarks= "insert into result(student_code,subject_code,mark) values ('".$student_code."','".$subject_code."','".$mark."')";
        $k = mysqli_query($dbc, $addmarks);
        if ($k)
        {
       $sms1='<font color="green"><b>Student Marks Submitted Successfully</b></font><br/>';
            include 'addmarks.php';
                        exit;
        }
        else
        {
            $sms1='<font color="red"><b>Failed To Add Student Marks</b></font><br/>';
            include 'addmarks.php';
                        exit;
        }
    }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is this a learning exercise or a real project? How much time do you have roughly? What part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: it's a diploma project, also i'm not that good in php thus why i prefer mysqli functions, the part which i real need help is how i can add all the six subjects at once for each student, plz help

Comment: Although it's useful to see that you have tried something, I suggest you remove all of this code (which appears to be irrelevant to your actual problem) and replace it with proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) AND a corresponding desired result

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post">
        <!-- Displays all users in database in a select option -->
        <select name="students">
            <option>Student 1</option>
            <option>Student 2</option>

            <?php
                //This code below is what you will need to use for yours to pull values out of the database(changing the values to suit yours obviously).

                // $query = "SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY student_name ASC";
                // $result = mysqli_query($conn,"$query");

                // while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                //     echo "<option>" . $row['student_name'] . "<br></option>";
                // }
            ?>

        </select><br>

        <!-- All the different input fields for maths, english and science -->

        <input type="text" name="eng_grade" value="" placeholder="Enter English Grade"><br>
        <input type="text" name="math_grade" value="" placeholder="Enter Maths Grade"><br>
        <input type="text" name="science_grade" value="" placeholder="Enter Science Grade"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php 

        //If submit is pressed
        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

            //this gets the value of the student name from the select box and stores it as $student
            $student = $_POST['students'];

            //These gets the values stored in the inputs above and store them in the 3 vairables
            $english = $_POST['eng_grade'];
            $maths = $_POST['math_grade'];
            $science = $_POST['science_grade'];

            //this is a mysql query that updates the data with whatever you put into the database(to add to existing tables you will have to dig abit deeper and create your
            //database with all the correct fields!
            $query = "UPDATE students SET maths_grade = '$maths', $english_grade = '$english', science_grade = '$science' WHERE student_name = '$student'";
            $update = mysqli_query($conn,  "$query"); //<-- this inserts the values into the database, changing the current #null value (null means nothing is in it)
        }

    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Edited again, if anymore help is needed just ask and ill make a short example

Comment: understood brother, the select box is perfect, so what i need is not an update query, is to select a student from that select box and then add the six subjects from there, now the php script to accomodate or insert all the six subjects at once and store them in the database with specific student id is a thing which i don't know where to start

Comment: Yes thats good! the update query is needed because you can leave the fields blank and update them by adding the values you type in. I will write you a script with comments etc if you would like?

Comment: Obviously you have to put your own values for the MySQL query in there but this is along the lines of what you want, I would suggest using this/ learning the syntax until you are comfortable and im sure by then you will posses the knowledge to do EXACTLY what you need to do

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 tables, one for student and other for marks.

In one table, just insert student name and id(unique), and in other table student all 6 subject marks i.e. 6 columns for 6 sub, 1 for student id, and other one as auto increment id column.

So using that student id you can retrieve all the subject marks of a particular student.

Comment: Enter 1 student name, then you'll get that student's id and using that you can enter all the 6 subjects marks at once.

Comment: the only thing that i have no idea is how to write the php script which will insert all the six subjects at once.

Comment: if that **student id** do not exists in db then insert it as :

`Insert into marks (student_id,sub1,sub2,sub3,sub4,sub5,sub6) values ('1',60,70,90,50,75,80)`

And if **student id exists** then either you can _update or let user not insert the record_

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Just noticed this question is 3 years old w00t!?

Drafting tables would be something like

student table:

```
id   primarykey  integer
name notnullable nvarchar(255)
```

subject table

```
id   primarykey  integer
name notnullable nvarchar(255)
```

student_subject table

```
 id         primarykey integer
 student_id foreignkey notnullable unique integer
 subject_id foreignkey notnullable unique integer
 mark                  notnullable        double(2,2)
```

E.g. Select the marks of a subject

```
Select student.name, subject.name, subject_student.mark from subject_student
inner join student on student.id = subject_student.student_id
inner join subjecton subject.id = subject_student.subject_id
where student_id = X; // X is the id of the student you want
```

Any calculation should be based on query, you don't want to store results in the database. You want data in the database and since it's volatil data (can be changed anytime), it's easier and faster to calculate whenever required. `Sum`, `GroupBy`, there are a ton of basic sql keywords that can help you. `student_subject table` is the table where it combines that Many students in Many subjects with a certain mark. If you want to save a student's mark, you just Insert into this table the id's and the mark value.

Since it's a school project, this should be suffice for you to work it out. 
In the future, take a look at prepared statements

> http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php